# Selenium, using xpath to click a button with a similar content

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to click a button that contains "Add" as text.
ie:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Add')])").click()
```

however it's not practical to do this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Add')])[1]").click()
```

It would be fine, except the page has a button with text "Add User", and it clicks that instead. Is there a way to only click it if it is EXACTLY "Add" and not just contains "Add"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try :

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Add").click()
```

`link text` will match links who's text equals `Add` and it doesn't match `text` which contains Add as part of it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Add']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your xpath to require an exact match instead of a partial match.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Add']").click()
```

Using `text()=` requires the text on the button to be equal to 'Add' and will not find other buttons that happen to contain the text 'Add'